# How to define an operator alias in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, alias, operator-keyword

Is there an easy way to define an operator alias for the `=` operator in PostgreSQL?

How is that solved for the `!=` and `<>` operator? Only the `<>` operator seems to be in pg_operators. Is the `!=` operator hard-coded?

This is needed for an application which uses a self-defined operator. In most environments this operator should act like a `=`, but there are some cases where we define a special behavior by creating an own operator and operator class. But for the normal case our operator should just be an alias for the `=` operator, so that it is transparent to the application which implementation is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check pgAdmin, the schema pg_catalog. It has all the operators and show you how the create them for all datatypes. Yes, you have to create them for all datatypes. So it's not just a single "alias", you need a lot of aliasses.

Example for a char = char, using !!!! as the alias:

```
CREATE OPERATOR !!!!   -- name
(
  PROCEDURE = pg_catalog.chareq,
  LEFTARG = "char",
  RIGHTARG = "char",
  COMMUTATOR = !!!!, -- the same as the name
  RESTRICT = eqsel,
  JOIN = eqjoinsel,
  HASHES,
  MERGES
);
SELECT 'a' !!!! 'a' -- true
SELECT 'a' !!!! 'b' -- false
```

Check the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) as well and pay attention to the naming rules, it has some restrictions.

Comment: Thats what i was doing until now. But to get indexes working with that operator too, i also have to define an operator class and family and have to create an additional index. For example for index `CREATE INDEX idx_fk1 ON tab (fk);` another index with the new op class `CREATE INDEX idx_fk2 ON tab (fk my_int4_ops);` is needed, so that both queries are able to use indexes: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tab WHERE fk = 1;` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tab WHERE fk !!!! 1;`. So i wondered if there is a way without creating a lot new indices.

Comment: A lot of work and a lot of room for errors. I would think again and search for a better solution.