# jooq: How to configure dialect for static DSL methods?

Tags: java, postgresql, configuration, jooq

I've got `dsl` with `POSTGRES_9_4` dialect. I try to use custom selection query with `org.jooq.impl.DSL.Condition`:

```
dsl.selectFrom(TAG_JSON).where(condition("translations ??| array[?]", normValues)).fetch(mapper);
```

It throws an exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class java.util.ArrayList is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:757)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:704)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.getDataType(DSL.java:14371)
    at org.jooq.impl.Utils.queryParts(Utils.java:1565)
    at org.jooq.impl.SQLImpl.<init>(SQLImpl.java:64)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.sql(DSL.java:6240)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.condition(DSL.java:7323)
```

Why `DEFAULT` dialect is used? How to configure global one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading. Your intention seems for `array[?]` to take a `List<String>` as a single bind value to pass to an array constructor. This won't work. You have two options:

Binding a single array

```
condition("translations <op> ?::text[]", normValues.toArray(new String[0]))
```

Binding the array as a list of bind values

```
condition("translations <op> {0}", list(
    normValues.stream().map(DSL::val).toArray(QueryPart[]::new)
))
```

This is using [`DSL.list()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#list-java.util.Collection-) to create a list of bind variables.

Note, in both cases, I have avoided your `??|` operator because jOOQ parses plain SQL text for bind values (`?`) and currently doesn't recognise `??|` as a non-bind variable sequence ([I've registered an issue for this](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5307)). If that operator has a textual alternative representation, I recommend using that instead.

Comment: I created [alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470418/how-to-define-an-operator-alias-in-postgresql) for `?|` operator

Comment: @fedor.belov: Oh interesting, I didn't know that this was possible. I suspect, if you create a textual alias in addition to the `??|` one, you can work around jOOQ's limitation here...