# How to convert "to_json()" PostgreSQL function in jOOQ?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, aggregate, jooq

I am trying to convert following PostgreSQL query into jOOQ and can't seem to find adequate method for solving this issue. Here's the query:

```
SELECT b.book_id AS b_id, b.title, b.price, b.amount, b.is_deleted,
to_json(array_agg(DISTINCT aut.*)) as authors, 
to_json(array_agg(DISTINCT cat.*)) as categories 
FROM book b 
LEFT JOIN author_book AS ab ON b.book_id = ab.book_id
LEFT JOIN author AS aut ON ab.author_id = aut.author_id
LEFT JOIN category_book AS cb ON b.book_id = cb.book_id
LEFT JOIN category AS cat ON cb.category_id = cat.category_id
GROUP BY b_id ORDER BY b_id ASC;
```

So far this is what I came up with in jOOQ:

```
    dslContext
   .select(BOOK.BOOK_ID, BOOK.TITLE, BOOK.PRICE, BOOK.AMOUNT, BOOK.IS_DELETED, 
           DSL.val(DSL.jsonArray(DSL.arrayAggDistinct(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID), 
                                 DSL.arrayAggDistinct(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME),
                                DSL.arrayAggDistinct(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME))
               ).cast(SQLDataType.JSON),                    
        DSL.val(DSL.jsonArray(DSL.arrayAggDistinct(CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID), 
                              DSL.arrayAggDistinct(CATEGORY.NAME), 
                              DSL.arrayAggDistinct(CATEGORY.IS_DELETED))
            ).cast(SQLDataType.JSON)
    ).from(BOOK
            .leftJoin(AUTHOR_BOOK).on(BOOK.BOOK_ID.eq(AUTHOR_BOOK.BOOK_ID))
            .leftJoin(AUTHOR).on(AUTHOR_BOOK.AUTHOR_ID.eq(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID))
            .leftJoin(CATEGORY_BOOK).on(BOOK.BOOK_ID.eq(CATEGORY_BOOK.BOOK_ID))
            .leftJoin(CATEGORY).on(CATEGORY_BOOK.CATEGORY_ID.eq(CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID))
    ).where(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID.eq(Long.valueOf(authorId))
    ).groupBy(BOOK.BOOK_ID).orderBy(BOOK.BOOK_ID.asc())
```

When I execute jOOQ code I get following exception:

> Type class org.jooq.impl.JSONArray is not supported in dialect DEFAULT

I've googled this exception and found only this similar exception in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37485419/6805866) question. Is there any proper way-workaround to solve this conversion of PostgreSQL `to_json` function and combination of array_agg() which holds DISTINCT on all fields of given aut(hor)/cat(egory) table?

**UPDATE**:
This is another way I used to write a query in jOOQ in NON-type-safe way:

```
dslContext.resultQuery(DBQueries.GET_ALL_BOOKS_BY_AUTHOR_ID, Long.valueOf(authorId)));
```

...and here is the code for `DBQueries.GET_ALL_BOOKS_BY_AUTHOR_ID` variable:

```
public class DBQueries {
//...
static String GET_ALL_BOOKS_BY_AUTHOR_ID = "SELECT b.book_id AS b_id, b.title, b.price, b.amount, b.is_deleted, " +
            "to_json(array_agg(DISTINCT aut.*)) as authors, to_json(array_agg(DISTINCT cat.*)) as categories " +            
            "FROM book b " + 
            "LEFT JOIN author_book AS ab ON b.book_id = ab.book_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN author AS aut ON ab.author_id = aut.author_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN category_book AS cb ON b.book_id = cb.book_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN category AS cat ON cb.category_id = cat.category_id " +
            "WHERE aut.author_id = :id " + 
            "GROUP BY b_id ORDER BY b_id ASC;"; 
}
```

BTW, I've updated my question for it to be clear how I've used resultQuery() method to achieve what I want. I'm asking how to achieve this in jOOQ in as much as possible type-safe way for I have even more complex query which I don't know if it's possible to achieve by NOT using PostgreSQL `to_json()` function. For instance I would like to create something like [this](https://bytefish.de/blog/postgresql_json/) in jOOQ like in section "04_create_functions.sql" of submitted link of bytefish.de web site.

```
get_image
--------------------------------------------------------------
 {"imageid" : 1, 
  "hash" : "a3b0c44", 
  "description" : "Some Description", 
  "created_on" : "2015-03-09T22:00:45.111", 
  "comments" : [{"commentid":1, "imageid":1, "text":"Awesome!", "createdon":"2015-03-09T22:58:47.783"},
                {"commentid":2, "imageid":1, "text":"This is just a second comment.", "createdon" : "2015-03-09T22:58:47.783"}], 
  "tags" : [{"tagid":1,"name":"Cool"}, 
            {"tagid":2,"name":"Berlin"}]}
(1 row)
```

I'm trying to do same thing for a REPORT for (book) ORDERS in which query I have 8 tables involved (I didn't post that query here as I am trying to solve more simple problem in jOOQ which is to create JsonArray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your specific errors

- You're wrapping a `Field` expression (`DSL.jsonArray()`) in [`DSL.val()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/), which is meant for bind values. That doesn't work, and is the cause of your exception
- However, you cannot yet turn an ordinary array into a `JSON` array by wrapping them that way. jOOQ doesn't know that what you mean by this is calling `to_json` behind the scenes. As of jOOQ 3.13, you will have to resort to using some [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/bind-values/) (see example below), or alternatively, you fetch an array without turning that into JSON in your SQL logic, and turn it into JSON only in your Java client logic.

Plain SQL templating example:

```java
DSL.field("to_json({0})", JSON.class, DSL.arrayAggDistinct(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID))
```

#### jOOQ 3.14 JSON support

Note that jOOQ 3.14 will support *much* more JSON functionality via standard SQL JSON API, and SQL Server's `FOR JSON` clause:

- [`JSON_ARRAY`, `JSON_OBJECT`, `JSON_VALUE` function support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/)
- [`JSON_ARRAYAGG` support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/json-arrayagg-function/)
- [`JSON_OBJECTAGG` support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/json-objectagg-function/)
- [`JSON_TABLE` table valued function support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/json-table-function/)
- [`JSON_EXISTS` predicate support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/json-exists-predicate/)

And:

- [SQL Server `FOR JSON` syntax support and emulation](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/05/05/using-sql-server-for-xml-and-for-json-syntax-on-other-rdbms-with-jooq/)

Comment: If I understood you correctly you are suggesting to use "plain SQL templating" to build final result by using something as **named/inlined parameters** and take out AUTHORS and CATEGORIES as plain ARRAY of values ORR to use something like `resultQuery​(String plainSQL, Object.. bindings)` method where I would pass  plain written SQL query and (in this case) value of authorId (by which I am performing search) in ONE go (but that is NOT type-safe way)?

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear about what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @NikolaS: No, not for the entire query, just for that function call! I'll update my answer

Comment: @Lukas_Eder: I've listened to your advice, looked through documentation and adjusted my jOOQ code by following your and Docs example. Solution can be see in my own answer and if you have any suggestions/comments please let me know. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: @NikolaS: Perfect, thanks for documenting your own solution here, as an answer. People should do this more often!

Answer (score 1):

As @Lukas_Eder pointed out to solve this issue it's needed to create JSON object via plain SQL templating like in following example:

```
DSL.field("to_json({0})", JSON.class, DSL.arrayAggDistinct(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID))
```

I've read bit more about above mentioned method in documentation and got idea how to modify method for my own need (in order to be equal to one posted in question in PostgreSQL syntax):

```
DSL.field( "to_json(array_agg(DISTINCT author.*))", JSON.class, DSL.arrayAgg(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID) ).as("authors")
```

Comment: In the last example, you don't need to pass the `DSL.arrayAgg()` expression, because you don't have any template placeholder to match it to (e.g. `{0}`). However, you can still pass the `AUTHOR` table if you want, e.g. `DSL.field("to_json(array_agg(distinct {0}.*))", JSON.class, AUTHOR)`