# How to get operator definition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, alias, operator-keyword

I want to create [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470418/how-to-define-an-operator-alias-in-postgresql) for an operator. In this case I need its definition. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

This information is in `pg_operator` system catalog.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-operator.html for details.